# Delete single occurrence in google calendar

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I want to delete a single occurrence of a repeated event. This is my code:

```
private void handleActionDelete(long event, long occurrence) {
    final ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, Long.MIN_VALUE);
    ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] projection;
    projection = new String[]{CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN};
    String selection = "Instances." + CalendarContract.Instances._ID + " = ? AND " + CalendarContract.Instances
            .EVENT_ID + " = ?";
    String[] selArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(occurrence), Long.toString(event)};
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(eventsUri, projection, selection, selArgs, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        cursor.close();
        return;
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex
            (CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN)));
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_CANCELED);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI, String.valueOf(event));
    cursor.close();
    try {
        contentResolver.insert(uri, values);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

I already checked all other similar problems on stackoverflow but I didn't find any solution, maybe it's something related to my code, I hope someone can review it.

Comment: How are you saving the calendar event? In general terms the only thing you have to do is save it with an ID and to delete, search for that ID and delete the corresponding event.

Comment: I'm saving the event manually using the Google Calendar app, I create a repeated event

Answer (score -1):

if you use `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar` I suppose you already have **id** of the event you want to delete

the answer is right there in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete#auth) and states (I've copied the exact snippet from doc):

```
// Initialize Calendar service with valid OAuth credentials
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
.setApplicationName("applicationName").build();

// Delete an event
service.events().delete('primary', "eventId").execute();
```